# List of blocks to a whole matrix - java

Tags: java, matrix, block, transformation

So I'm having the following problem: I have a method that breaks a big matrix into smaller blocks of the same size. After I do some operations on the blocks, I want to reconstruct the big matrix in the right order, but I'm going wrong at it somehow.

The following code reconstructs correctly a 4x4 matrix that breaks into 2x2, but for any other dimensions, it's not working properly.

```
   public long[][] blocksToMatrix(List<long[][]> blocks, int blockDimension, int width, int height ){
      long[][] yuvMatrix = new long[height][width];
      int heightPos = 0;
      int widthPos = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++) {
         long[][] yuvBlock = blocks.get(i);
         int heightPosTemp = heightPos;
         for (int j = 0; j < blockDimension * blockDimension; j++) {
            yuvMatrix[heightPos][widthPos] = yuvBlock[j / blockDimension][j % blockDimension];
            widthPos++;
            if (widthPos >= width){
               widthPos = (i * blockDimension) % width;
               heightPos++;
            }
            if (widthPos == ((i + 1) * blockDimension) % width){
               widthPos = (i * blockDimension) % width;
               heightPos++;
            }
         }
         if (heightPos == height ){
            heightPos = heightPosTemp;
         }
         else {
            heightPos = (i * blockDimension) % height;
         }
         widthPos = ((i + 1) * blockDimension) % width;
      }
      return yuvMatrix;
   }
```

The method I used to break the matrix:

```
   public List<long[][]> matrixToBlocks(long[][] yuvMatrix, int blockDimension, int width, int height){
      int blocksSize = width / blockDimension * (height / blockDimension);
      List<long[][]> blocks = new ArrayList<long[][]>();
      for (int i = 0; i < blocksSize; i++) {
         long[][] subBlock = new long[blockDimension][blockDimension];
         int heightPos = (blockDimension * (i / blockDimension)) % height;
         int widthPos = (blockDimension * i) % width;
         if (widthPos + blockDimension > width) {
            widthPos = 0;
         }
         for (int row = 0; row < blockDimension; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < blockDimension; col++) {
               subBlock[row][col] = yuvMatrix[heightPos + row][col + widthPos];
            }
         }
         blocks.add(subBlock);
      }
      return blocks;
   }
```

The way I tested it:

```
   public static void testareMatBlo(int height, int width, int blockdim){
      long[][] test = new long[height][width];
      int val = 1;
      for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
         for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            test[i][j] = val;
            val++;
         }
      }
      List<long[][]> blocks = matrixToBlocks(test, blockdim, width, height);
      long[][] matrix = blocksToMatrix(blocks, blockdim, width, height);
      if (Arrays.deepEquals(test, matrix)){
         System.out.println("YES");
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("NO");
      }
   }
```

This works:

```
   testareMatBlo(4, 4, 2);
```

But anything else doesn't. Can anyone explain what I did wrong?

Comment: A few side notes on `matrixToBlocks(long[][] yuvMatrix, int blockDimension, int width, int height)` (and `blocksToMatrix(...)`):  assuming `width` and `height` mean the dimensions of the matrix you might not need them, since you'd already be able to get them like `yuvMatrix.length` and `yuvMatrix[0].length` (assuming you can trust the 2nd dimension always has the same size). Additionally you should make sure that `blockDimension` is a factor of the matrix dimensions, otherwise you might have difficulties in decomposing them into blocks (e.g. decompising a 5x5 matrix into 2x2 blocks).

Comment: Yeah, I already knew all that, but thank you for reminding me.. I was going to clean the methods after I got them to work, right now they are a bit messy.

Comment: You'r `blocksToMatrix(...)` is missing some code: ` long[][] yuvBlock = blocks.get(i);` - `i` isn't defined in the code you posted.

Comment: @Thomas you are correct, I have accidentally copy-pasted the wrong thing. Fixed this, but it still doesn't work, same problem `testareMatBlo(4, 4, 2);` works, anything else doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't thoroughly read your code for `matrixToBlocks(...)` but all those calculations like `int blocksSize = width / blockDimension * (height / blockDimension);` are very likely to introduce hard to spot errors - and you actually don't need them:

```
public static List<long[][]> matrixToBlocks(long[][] yuvMatrix, int blockDimension){    
  //Check matrix and block dimension match
  if( yuvMatrix.length == 0 || yuvMatrix.length % blockDimension != 0 
    || yuvMatrix[0].length == 0 || yuvMatrix[0].length % blockDimension != 0 ) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("whatever message you like");
  }

  List<long[][]> blocks = new ArrayList<long[][]>();

  //Iterate over the blocks in row-major order (down first, then right)
  for( int c = 0; c < yuvMatrix.length; c += blockDimension ) {
    for( int r = 0; r < yuvMatrix[c].length; r += blockDimension ) {
      long[][] subBlock = new long[blockDimension][blockDimension];

      //Iterate over the block in row-major order
      for(int bc = 0; bc < blockDimension; bc++ ) {
        for(int br = 0; br < blockDimension; br++ ) {
          subBlock[bc][br]=yuvMatrix[c+bc][r+br];
        } 
      }    

      blocks.add(subBlock);
    }
  }

  return blocks;
}
```

That method doesn't look shorter but it is: discounting the preliminary check yours is missing there are only 8 actual lines of code compared to 13 in your code. That's not the point however. What's more important is that the logic is easier since there are only a few calculations involved (like `c+bc`).

You might think this is inefficient but it isn't: you're accessing each element only once and thus even though there are 4 nested loops the overall complexity is still O(n) with n being the size of the matrix.

Constructing the matrix back is equally easy. The major thing you need to take care of is the ordering of the blocks: if you create them in row-major order (blocks below each other are next to each other in the list) you need to recreate the matrix in the same way:

```
public static long[][] blocksToMatrix( List<long[][]> blocks, int width, int height ) {
  long[][] yuvMatrix = new long[width][height];
  int c = 0;
  int r = 0;

  for( long[][] block : blocks ) {
    int blockWidth = block.length;
    int blockHeight = block[0].length;

    for( int bc = 0; bc < block.length; bc++ ) {
      for( int br = 0; br < block[bc].length; br++ ) {
        yuvMatrix[c + bc][r + br] = block[bc][br];
      }
    }

    //calculate the next offset into the matrix
    //The blocks where created in row-major order so we need to advance the offset in the same way
    r += blockHeight;
    if( r >= height ) {
      r = 0;
      c += blockWidth;
    }
  }

  return yuvMatrix;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, this looks much cleaner, but still, the problem with recreating the matrix, the `blocksToMatrix(...)` method, persists.

Comment: This is great, thank you. Everything seems much cleaner now. There still seems to be a small problem though, the test seems to fail for the following arguments `testareMatBlo(800, 600, 8);`

Comment: @Pred that seems to be a problem of switched parameters: you pass `height = 800` and `width = 600` but I assume internally you swap those and pass 600 and 800 to `blocksToMatrix(...)`. You'd then get a 800x600 matrix instead of the 600x800 matrix you split into blocks and those clearly are not equal (notation normally is width x height).

Comment: You are right once again, thank you, you've been of great help.